# How to add extensions to Opera Neon

Tags: windows, browser-addons, opera

I searched a lot about how to add extensions or add-ons to Opera Neon, but the answer for such-type questions is still the same. You can't add extensions to Opera Neon.

Comment: Windows is POSIX compliant, yet you can't run Linux programs on it. Just because something is based on something else, doesn't mean it has the same support.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I don't understand. I talk about Opera Neon for Windows. I want to add an addon to it. Somehow. I don't want to run any Linux programs. (Opera Neon, Opera, Chrome and Chromium are all for Windows as far as I know)

Comment: You cannot. Opera Neon is a one-time concept product that will not be further developed in the future. It will rapidly fall behind, so is really not recommended in spite of its speed.

Comment: @harrymc But that does not mean I can not use it or adjust it to myself

Comment: You certainly can, but this isn't recommended in the long-term, since with time this browser will fall behind in all respects, including new malware threats.

Comment: @harrymc cool, but still not helpful to my question at all

Comment: Find the source code if that's applicable, look through the logic, and figure out how to get extensions installed. Just as your research has led you to the same answer as it's not possible or whatever, that simply seems to be the case since it was not developed to support extensions apparently. If it's worth it to you and you can find the source code if you're legally allowed to adjust for your custom needs, put in that effort; otherwise, it's a moot point since it was never developed to support extensions so I'm not sure what's so hard to understand. I'll gladly up vote a working solution.

Comment: You'd probably need to develop and test the extensions yourself as well if you can figure out what to change in the code to make that even possible I would suppose. Good luck finding someone to put in all that effort and time for a 50 point bounty man!!

Comment: Thank you, I think yours is the most useful answer here. I would give more, but I don't know, how to change a bounty reward during bounty

Answer (score 1):

What must be considered regarding extensions in any application is that the application must have the functionality programed into it.

While Opera Neon may be based on Opera, the current staff at Opera do not, and have not had the same vision of usability that the original developer of Opera who has not been with Opera for a long time, had.

The ability to support extensions was intentionally programmed out of Opera as the current developer team is of the opinion that extensions that make web browsers more user friendly and able to serve the user's needs, are unnecessary.

Sadly, the mentality of not serving the user's needs is currently spreading across the developer community and is evident in the way Firefox has not only limited it's flagship browser, but introduced bugs as well.

Neon is based on the concept that new is always better even if you cannot do with the new, what you are able to do with the old.

If you wish to add extensions to your browser, you have no choice but to either stick with the previous version of Opera or, change over to a browser where the developer community retains and supports that vision that a browser should and ought to be flexible enough to support the user's needs. Not hinder their browsing experience.

Comment: I agree, but this is not the case. Opera Neon is just a visual design concept of a browser, therefore my issue shouldn't be a problem. But somehow this concept is best browser I've ever used and for Windows (which is very limited unlike other operating systems) it is as brave as Maxthon is.

Comment: If you're saying that Neon is just an alternate theme for Opera, then the solution to the problem is to separate the Neon theme from Opera Neon and add it to Opera. In that way, you should be able to add any extensions to Opera you desire.

 If however, the Neon theme hides the necessary menu bar item, then you will have to edit the theme so that it does not hide the menu bar item.

Answer (score 1):

Just because one program is based on another one, does not necessarily mean that it is capable of doing the same things. You cannot add extensions to Opera Neon. It is not able to run them.

Modern programs designed for MS Windows or other graphical operating systems consist of numerous interconnected sub-components. In the case of web browsers, these include:

- window & menu [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) (some of this will be provided by the OS)
- [page rendering engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_layout_engines) (such as Gecko or WebKit)
- [JavaScript interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines) (such as V8 or Rhino)
- extension APIs (such as ActiveX or [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI))
- user preferences, cache, and other file storage choices

Although Neon uses Blink, the same layout engine as Chromium, **it does not include the code needed to run Chrome-style extensions**.

Comment: Cool, but I just suggested my thoughts. I am still searching for a solution, I am not asking for an explanation, how modern programs works. Although AskUbuntu and StackOverflow are great websites, it looks like SuperUser is not as good as its sisters.

Comment: Other than asking Opera for the source code and changing it yourself, THERE IS NO SOLUTION to what you seek. Opera Neon in its current form CANNOT use extensions, for the reasons I explained.

Comment: The problem is not SuperUser's inability to answer your question. The problem is your inability to accept the answer.

Comment: But none of the answers here are answering my question. I understand there was none possibility found yet, but I don't understand, why so many people tries to explain me, what I knew before.

Comment: What is your question? What is your question? WHAT IS YOUR QUESTION? Your original post "How to add extensions to Opera Neon" has been thoroughly answered: YOU CAN'T. There is no other possible answer. If that isn't what you are asking, then edit your post and state it clearly.

Comment: My question is clear and doesn't need any further edits. I know I can't, but maybe somebody can or knows a way or finds a way, how to make it possible.

Comment: This is TRTWF. You don't understand the difference between "we don't know how to do it" and "we know it cannot be done". Opera specifically says that Neon does not include the code necessary to run extensions. You may as well ask how to use FFMPEG to convert Word DOCs into PDFs.

Comment: It is like a hardware question of type: "My touchpad stopped working." answers like those here would be: "Yes, your touchpad stopped working. You should accept it." Would this answer be satisfying for you, if you imagine your touchpad accidentally stopped working? Or like another answer here: "Touchpads usually stop working. You should switch to proper mouse and don't use touchpads." Satisfying answer, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57860/discussion-between-foo-bar-and-aleskva).